# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight[512, 3, 1, 1, 1], so expected input[32, 1, 6, 4, 4] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Described Error-

```py
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight[512, 3, 1, 1, 1], so expected input[32, 1, 6, 4, 4] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

I am aware that this issue type has been raised several times, but none of them helped me solved my issue.
I am trying to Implement a `FutureGAN model` from here- https://github.com/TUM-LMF/FutureGAN

I followed all the steps mentioned in the Description and finally ran -

```
python /content/FutureGAN/train.py --data_root='/content/mmnist-2/train'
```

https://github.com/TUM-LMF/FutureGAN/blob/master/train.py

This yields an error -

```
 ... loading training configuration ... 
 ... saving training configuration to <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./logs/2021-08-24_172412/train_config.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
 ... creating initial models ... 
 ... initial models have been built successfully ... 
 ... saving initial model strutures to <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./logs/2021-08-24_172412/initial_model_structure_4x4.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
  0% 0/10140 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/FutureGAN/train.py", line 832, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "/content/FutureGAN/train.py", line 574, in train
    self.z_x_gen = self.G(self.z)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/FutureGAN/model.py", line 307, in forward
    y = self.model(x)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 67, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 67, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/FutureGAN/custom_layers.py", line 114, in forward
    x = self.conv(x.mul(self.scale))
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 388, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
  File "/usr/local/envs/FutureGAN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 126, in conv3d
    return f(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight[512, 3, 1, 1, 1], so expected input[32, 1, 6, 4, 4] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

I could resolve this issue by providing an input of just 1 channel,

```
python /content/FutureGAN/train.py --data_root='/content/mmnist-2/train' --nc 1
```

but that is not exactly how I wish to solve this. I would want my input to be in the RGB form.

Here are the details of my environment -
I am using a google colab notebook to do the training with all the steps here -
It is a regular Colab environment with Conda installed with  all dependencies.

https://github.com/dhruvsheth-ai/FutureGAN/blob/master/FutureGAN-new.ipynb

Here is the attached Model Architecture -

```
--------------------------------------------------
Sequences in Dataset:  16199
Global iteration step:  1014 , Epoch:  2
Phase:  init
Number of Generator`s model parameters: 
35659778
Number of Discriminator`s model parameters: 
66603521
--------------------------------------------------
New Generator structure: 
FutureGenerator(
  (model): Sequential(
    (concat_block_encode): Concat(
      (layer1): Sequential(
        (low_resl_from_rgb): Sequential(
          (from_rgb_block): Sequential(
            (0): EqualizedConv3d(
              (conv): Conv3d(1, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
            )
            (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
            (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
            )
          )
        )
        (low_resl_downsample): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
        )
      )
      (layer2): Sequential(
        (high_resl_from_rgb): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(1, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
        )
        (high_resl_block_encode): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
          (3): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2), bias=False)
          )
          (4): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (5): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
        )
      )
    )
    (fadein_block_encode): FadeInLayer(
    )
    (middle_block): Sequential(
      (0): EqualizedConv3d(
        (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
      )
      (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
      (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
      )
      (3): EqualizedConv3d(
        (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(6, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
      )
      (4): LeakyReLU(0.2)
      (5): PixelwiseNormLayer(
      )
      (6): EqualizedConvTranspose3d(
        (deconv): ConvTranspose3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(6, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
      )
      (7): LeakyReLU(0.2)
      (8): PixelwiseNormLayer(
      )
      (9): EqualizedConv3d(
        (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
      )
      (10): LeakyReLU(0.2)
      (11): PixelwiseNormLayer(
      )
    )
    (concat_block_decode): Concat(
      (layer1): Sequential(
        (low_resl_upsample): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConvTranspose3d(
            (deconv): ConvTranspose3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
        )
        (low_resl_to_rgb): Sequential(
          (to_rgb_block): Sequential(
            (0): EqualizedConv3d(
              (conv): Conv3d(512, 1, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
            )
          )
        )
      )
      (layer2): Sequential(
        (high_resl_block_decode): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConvTranspose3d(
            (deconv): ConvTranspose3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (2): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
          (3): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          )
          (4): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (5): PixelwiseNormLayer(
          )
        )
        (high_resl_to_rgb): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 1, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
    (fadein_block_decode): FadeInLayer(
    )
  )
)
--------------------------------------------------
New Discriminator structure: 
Discriminator(
  (model): Sequential(
    (concat_block): Concat(
      (layer1): Sequential(
        (low_resl_from_rgb): Sequential(
          (from_rgb_block): Sequential(
            (0): EqualizedConv3d(
              (conv): Conv3d(1, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
            )
            (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          )
        )
        (low_resl_downsample): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
        )
      )
      (layer2): Sequential(
        (high_resl_from_rgb): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(1, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
        )
        (high_resl_block): Sequential(
          (0): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          )
          (1): LeakyReLU(0.2)
          (2): EqualizedConv3d(
            (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2), bias=False)
          )
          (3): LeakyReLU(0.2)
        )
      )
    )
    (fadein_block): FadeInLayer(
    )
    (last_block): Sequential(
      (0): MinibatchStdConcatLayer(averaging = all)
      (1): EqualizedConv3d(
        (conv): Conv3d(513, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
      )
      (2): LeakyReLU(0.2)
      (3): EqualizedConv3d(
        (conv): Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(12, 4, 4), stride=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
      )
      (4): LeakyReLU(0.2)
      (5): Flatten(
      )
      (6): EqualizedLinear(
        (linear): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1, bias=False)
      )
    )
  )
)
--------------------------------------------------
```

This model has also been tested on KTH dataset, containing Action images (RGB), but the error pertains.

**Would appreciate any suggestions and if possible the change to be made in the code to solve this issue. Thanks!**

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could provide exact modifications to code :)

Comment: You are using a model that expects three-channel images, you are using MNIST which has grayscale images. Could you print your model's summary?

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I tested the model on KTH dataset consisting of RGB images as well. But the error remains the same. I have updated the question with the model summary. Thanks!